# jasmine integration with backbone leads to - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined in HtmlReporter()

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine

I am trying to integrate Jasmine (v2.3.4) for a backbone js application as per some examples and documentation found in the net. Some content used from the following links mentioned.

http://kilon.org/blog/2012/08/testing-backbone-requirejs-applications-with-jasmine/
http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/setting-up-a-jasmine-unit-testing-environment-with-testem/

All steps were clearly implemented but I am getting following type error **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined" in jasmine-html.js HtmlReporter function.**

I see HtmlReporter takes a options param but I am not sure what to pass to this method. Appreciate any help on this topic.

I have put the following code in my require config - 'jasmine': {
            exports: 'jasmine'
        },
        'jasmine-html': {
            deps: ['jasmine'],
            exports: 'jasmine'
        },
        "boot":{
            deps:["jasmine"],
            exports: 'jasmine'
        }

require([], function(){

```
var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;

var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter(); // ***this is leading to Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined***

jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);

jasmineEnv.specFilter = function(spec) {
    return htmlReporter.specFilter(spec);
};

var specs = [];

specs.push('SearchSpec');


$(function(){
    require(specs, function(){
        jasmineEnv.execute();
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`require.config({
    paths:{
        jasmine: 'path/jasmine',
        'jasmine-html': 'path/jasmine-html',
        'jasmine-boot': 'path/boot',
    },
    shim:{
        'jasmine-html': {
            deps: ['jasmine'],
        },
        'jasmine-boot': {
            deps: ['jasmine', 'jasmine-html'],
        },
})`;

`require(['jasmine-boot'], function () {
  require([
    'spec'
    ], function(){
    //trigger Jasmine
    window.onload();
  });
});`
`//spec.js
define(
    ['path/to/module'],
    function(MyModule) {
    describe('test',function() {})
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script data-main="/js/main" src="/js/lib/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'test/spec/collections/companyCollection.spec', 
        'test/spec/models/companyDivisionsModel.spec' 
    ], function () {
        window.onload();
    });
```

Comment: Very easy  and comfortable place this code to your specRunner.html file